# .text not getting all text, but works in console

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get text from a table cell class. The script works great in the console. However, when I implement the code it only grabs part of the text.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var getCustomText = $( "td.product-title-cell" ).text();
    $(function () {
        $('#idToPutCustomText').val(getCustomText);
    });
</script>
```

**The TD I am trying to get the text**

```
<td class="product-title-cell"> <a href="/products/yellow-unicorn-award-trophy">Yellow Unicorn Award Trophy - 2014 / The Weird Animal Awards / Presented To: adsf / For: asdf2 / Additional Text: asdf3</a> </td>
```

**The Text that I am actually getting**

Yellow Unicorn Poo Trophy - 2014 / The Weird Animal Awards

**Notes**

'Presented To' and all text thereafter are getting called from somewhere. I have not been able to figure that out yet. This leads me to believe that the call to presented to is happening after my script is being loaded.

**How I have tried to make my script load last**

- I have placed it right before and after the closing body tag.
- I have placed the code in it's own file and called on it using. The script got called, but it didn't get any text though.

  ```
  var theScript = document.createElement("script");
  theScript.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
  theScript.setAttribute("src","//www.mysite.com/script.js");
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(theScript);
  ```

**Questions**

- Is there any other reason why the text is getting cut off other than
  that it is loading last?
- If not, what is a sure fire way for my script to be loaded absolutely
  last?

Comment: The problem is the content of getCustomText? Can you provide a demo on jsfiddle?

Comment: Are you sure there's no script adding some text to the element _after_ you have executed your script?

Comment: @Answerers `$(document).ready()` is practically invoked when parser meets the closing `body` tag. There would be no difference when using  `$(document).ready()` in OP's case #1.

Comment: I did try to add in $(document).ready() to no prevail. It still is only doing part of the text. Thanks though, I am still a noob practicing so this helped me grow nonetheless.

Comment: @docwho have you checked the code? There might be some AJAX stuff dynamically adding content to the element you're reading, or some content is added in a `window.onload` handler. Or you've some invalid HTML, and the content is only partially returned. Please show all the relevant HTML for `td.product-title-cell`. (In my previous comment the end part should had been "... instead of OP's case #1.")

Comment: @Teemu This is how I see td.product-title-cell in the source code.

<td class="product-title-cell">
<a href="/products/yellow-unicorn-award-trophy">Yellow Unicorn Award Trophy - 2014 / The Weird Animal Awards / Presented To: adsf / For: asdf2 / Additional Text: asdf3</a>
</td>

Comment: @Teemu This is a shopify site that I just started working on today. I am not sure how the user text is getting applied, and it doesn't follow Shopify's advice on how to do it. It is a method which I can't find. One of my tasks was to get user generated text and apply it to a hidden form. stevieawards.myshopify.com/products/bronze-stevie-award-trophy . Please look, add custom text, go to checkout. I have removed all this code since it is a production site. However, you might be able to see why it isn't grabbing the custom text.

Comment: @docwho Your code seems to work at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3u785jos/). Are you sure you can see all the text within `#idToPutCustomText`? If that element is an `input`? Or it has some style/property which truncates the content?

Answer (score 1):

This is the point of using [`document.ready`](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) in jQuery. It waits untill all the DOM elements have been loaded, then executes the script:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var getCustomText = $( "td.product-title-cell" ).text();
    $('#idToPutCustomText').val(getCustomText);
});
```

Comment: I did try to add in $(document).ready() to no prevail. It still is only grabbing part of the sentence and not the custom text within the sentence. Thanks though, I really am dumbfounded by this.

Comment: @docwho Then could you show us your HTML for that item. It may be either you are running a script after this to change the content or the other part is not within `td.product-title-cell`.

Comment: This is how I see td.product-title-cell in the source code. <td class="product-title-cell"> <a href="/products/yellow-unicorn-award-trophy">Yellow Unicorn Award Trophy - 2014 / The Weird Animal Awards / Presented To: adsf / For: asdf2 / Additional Text: asdf3</a> </td>

Comment: @docwho This part seems to be generated dynamically from the server: `Presented To: adsf / For: asdf2 / Additional Text: asdf3`. You will need to ensure that that is code is being executed after that event. That's all the advice I can give with the provided information.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to load ALL your jQuery action inside a ready wrapper, like so:

```
$(function(){
  // jQuery now available
  var getCustomText = $( "td.product-title-cell" ).text();
  $('#idToPutCustomText').val(getCustomText);
);
```

You were already half-way there .. you just left that first line outside :)

Comment: I tried this without luck to. Both within $(document).ready() and without it. Still no luck. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

This works http://jsfiddle.net/mpwzu78w/

You must select the link. You could give the link a class or id.

```
var getCustomText = $("a").text();

alert(getCustomText);
```